# Convert long int seconds to double precision floating-point value

Tags: c++, date, datetime, time, converters

I have a long int variable wich containes seconds since Jan. 1, 1970 in this format:

```
long int seconds = 1231241242144214;
```

i need to convert this seconds to  double precision floating-point value. The integer part of the value is the number of days since midnight, 30 December 1899.
The fractional part of the value represents time. .5 is equal to 12:00 PM.

how can i convert?

Comment: What a terrible representation.  It should be in a long int.  There is no guarantee of preserving precision when you convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `86400` seconds in a day, and `25569` days between these epochs. So the answer is:

```
double DelphiDateTime = (UnixTime / 86400.0) + 25569;
```

You really do need to store the Unix time in an integer variable though.

Comment: @Baum Yah, I realised that too. Am too used to coding in Delphi! Thanks.